# $G$ has exactly $n$ different subgroups of prime order $p$, then total number of elements of $p$ is $m(p-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> ***$A$ and $B$ are two distinct subgroups of group $G$ s.t. $o(A)=o(B)=p=prime$, show that $A\cap B=\{e\}$.***
>
> ***Deduce that if $G$ has exactly $n$ different subgroups of prime order $p$, then total number of elements of order $p$ is $n(p-1)$.***

I can solve the 1st part by using Lagrange's theorem. I am unable to deduce the 2nd part by applying the 1st part. Please help me to deduce the 2nd part based on Lagrange's theorem (**without using isomorphism etc**).

Comment: In the second part, do you mean *"...then the total number of elements of order $p$ is $n(p-1)$"*?

Comment: Just...count them. How many elements of order $p$ occur in more than one subgroup of order $p$?

Comment: A group of order $p$ is cyclic and is generated by every of its non-trivial elements (Lagrange's Theorem), which in turn have order $p$.